# How do you use the time value of the timeUpdate event to trigger an AMP animation?

Tags: amp-html

The `<amp-video>` component emits a `timeUpdate` event documented [here](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/interaction_dynamic/amp-actions-and-events#amp-video,-amp-youtube). However it is not at all clear how the time value can be used.

I have amp animations that I want to trigger at various times. In JavaScript, I would pass that time value to my event handler and trigger my animations based on that time value.

How can I do something similar in AMP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the animation can be expressed in terms of [`<amp-animation>`](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-animation) then:

**Step 1**

Convert the times your animation needs to trigger to a percentage offset. For example if you want to trigger an animation at 45s, and your video is 1m20s long,  then the offset would be 45/80 = 0.5625:

```
<amp-animation id="myAnimation" ...>
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      // ...
      "animations": [{
        "opacity": 1,
        "offset": 0.5625
      }]
    }
  </script>
</amp-animation>
```

**Step 2**

Connect the `timeUpdate` event fired by the video to the [`seekTo`](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-animation#on-actions) action of the `<amp-animation>`:

```
<amp-video on="timeUpdate:myAnimation.seekTo(percent=event.percent)" ...>
</amp-video>
```

See [this example](https://codepen.io/aghassemi/pen/JpGwXP) for more details.

(Note that this approach does not work within the context of AMP Stories, since the `<amp-animation>` component is (as of August 2018) [not allowed](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/98d015b21567a4fc18fe3c81c93ecc6aa0b2518b/extensions/amp-story/validator-amp-story.protoascii#L482-L570). Actions and events are also not supported.)